# Is it possible to overload a function with different numbers of arguments (using traits)

Tags: rust

I'm trying to have a `new` constructor with one and with two arguments, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Is this even possible at the moment?

What I have now gives me an error that multiple applicable items are in scope ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4a7c13ebcd73abfcebdc5eaaf40d9ad0&version=stable&backtrace=0))

```
trait __Constructor1<T> {
    fn new(T) -> Self;
}
trait __Constructor2<T, U> {
    fn new(T, U) -> Self;
}

enum MixedInts {
    SmallInt(i32),
    TwoSmallInts(i32, i32),
}

impl __Constructor1<i32> for MixedInts {
    fn new(__0: i32) -> MixedInts {
        MixedInts::SmallInt(__0)
    }
}
impl __Constructor2<i32, i32> for MixedInts {
    fn new(__0: i32, __1: i32) -> MixedInts {
        MixedInts::TwoSmallInts(__0, __1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MixedInts::new(2i32);
    let y = MixedInts::new(2i32, 2i32);
}
```

Comment: I know you've just tried to create a small example.. but the trait usage here is pretty useless. Turning your example on its head slightly, I [have seen this technique used in a few codebases](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2ae7e995af81de014bd8a59971021649&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'm not sure what your code is supposed to achieve. It does not accept a different number of arguments at all and for some reason it creates a second type instead of the enum.

Comment: The purpose is to demonstrate the _use of an enum_ as a way to "overload" the function. You can use an enum variant to pass different numbers of arguments into the function. So it flips your example on its head by using an enum as the mechanism to "overload" - I just used a struct as an example to highlight that the enum in my example is the main part.

Answer (score 35):

Rust doesn't support overloaded functions/methods. As a workaround, you can use tuples to receive multiple values in a single argument. You can then define a trait and implement it for the admissible types of that single argument, and the function will simply delegate to the trait's implementation.

```
enum MixedInts {
    SmallInt(i32),
    TwoSmallInts(i32, i32),
}

trait IntoMixedInts {
    fn into(self) -> MixedInts;
}

impl MixedInts {
    fn new<A>(args: A) -> MixedInts
        where A: IntoMixedInts
    {
        args.into()
    }
}

impl IntoMixedInts for i32 {
    fn into(self) -> MixedInts {
        MixedInts::SmallInt(self)
    }
}

impl IntoMixedInts for (i32, i32) {
    fn into(self) -> MixedInts {
        MixedInts::TwoSmallInts(self.0, self.1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MixedInts::new(2i32);
    let y = MixedInts::new((2i32, 2i32));
}
```

**Note:** In this example, you could use the standard `From` and `Into` traits instead of defining your own trait. It might not work for other traits, though, due to the coherence rules (the rules that ensure that there can only exist one implementation of a certain trait for a certain type).

```
enum MixedInts {
    SmallInt(i32),
    TwoSmallInts(i32, i32),
}

impl MixedInts {
    fn new<A>(args: A) -> MixedInts
        where A: Into<MixedInts>
    {
        args.into()
    }
}

impl From<i32> for MixedInts {
    fn from(a: i32) -> MixedInts {
        MixedInts::SmallInt(a)
    }
}

impl From<(i32, i32)> for MixedInts {
    fn from((a, b): (i32, i32)) -> MixedInts {
        MixedInts::TwoSmallInts(a, b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MixedInts::new(2i32);
    let y = MixedInts::new((2i32, 2i32));
}
```

Comment: Note: Rust does support overloading via traits; it seems less practical than using Into/From, but it is supported.

Answer (score 16):

It is *technically* possible, but not in a way that's practical. You need to use Rust's [Universal Function Call Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ufcs.html) in order for it to disambiguate the calls to `new`.

```
fn main() {
    let x = <MixedInts as __Constructor1<i32>>::new(2i32);
    let y = <MixedInts as __Constructor2<i32, i32>>::new(2i32, 2i32);
}
```

The Iron framework has an interesting [Modifier pattern](http://ironframework.io/doc/modifier/trait.Modifier.html) that I *think* accomplishes what you want. While it's pretty clever, it's ultimately confusing to the user.

Comment: 404 on the link

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest making use of the `From`/`Into` traits in the standard library.

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
enum MixedInts {
    SmallInt(i32),
    TwoSmallInts(i32, i32),
}

impl From<i32> for MixedInts {
    fn from(n: i32) -> Self {
        MixedInts::SmallInt(n)
    }
}

impl From<(i32, i32)> for MixedInts {
    fn from((a, b): (i32, i32)) -> Self {
        MixedInts::TwoSmallInts(a, b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: MixedInts = 2_i32.into();
    assert_eq!(x, MixedInts::SmallInt(2));

    let y: MixedInts = (2_i32, 2_i32).into();
    assert_eq!(y, MixedInts::TwoSmallInts(2, 2));
}
```

[example on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9b5994910cb82da84f892f69d26caacf&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Could you clarify how this differs from [the existing answer that suggests using `From` and `Into`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42238787/155423)?

Comment: The only difference is that I replaced the code inside main to make use of the From/Into implementations.