# Is there a way to `overload` the same method but with different parameters?

Tags: generics, rust, overloading, traits

It was a beautiful day until I saw python's Tkinter ability to get/set data on a value, like follows:

```py
k = some_object(inner=7)
print(k.inner()) # Gets the value, prints 7
k.inner(4) # Sets the value
print(k.inner()) # 4
```

I was impressed - that is very cool! No need to write all these pesky `set_data` or `get_data`, just a single method that decides what to do all by itself!

But then I tried the same thing in Rust.
Firstly, that `inner` can't be a function, since Rust's functions do not support overloading. This problem is often solved by manually implementing `FnOnce`, `FnMut` and `Fn` on some unit type and then declaring a constant of that unit(see [overloadf crate](https://crates.io/crates/overloadf)). Although it requires some nightly features, I am currently using nightly Rust so it's not a problem.

But what *is* a problem is that method takes `self` as an argument(that's why it's method and not a function), and you cannot 'call' a constant using dot notation:

```rust
#![feature(fn_traits, unboxed_closures)]

/// Some `sort` of a function
pub struct Functor;

impl FnOnce for Functor { ... }

impl FnMut for Functor { ... }

impl Fn for Functor { ... }

#[allow(#[allow(non_upper_case_globals)])]
pub const i_am_a_normal_function_trust_me: Functor = Functor;

// ...

i_am_a_normal_function_trust_me() // Yay! Could be called!

pub struct Wrapper(());

impl Wrapper {
    /// Let's just say that `Functor` takes a `&Wrapper`
    #[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
    pub const method: Functor = Functor;
}

let v = Wrapper(());

// Oopsy, does not work
v.method()

// Only through that ugly notation(which is not what I want)
Wrapper::method(&v)
```

This does not compile, so I tried an another approach - through ordinary traits:

```rust
pub trait GetInner <T> {
    fn inner(&self) -> &T;
}

pub trait SetInner <T> {
    fn inner(&mut self, inner: T);
}

pub struct Wrapper <T> (T);

impl <T> GetInner <T> for Wrapper <T> {
    fn inner(&self) -> &T {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl <T> SetInner <T> for Wrapper <T> {
    fn inner(&mut self, inner: T) {
        self.0 = inner
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Wrapper(0);
    dbg!(v.inner());
    v.inner(4); // error[E0061]: this function takes 0 arguments but 1 argument was supplied
    dbg!(v.inner());
    v.inner(v.inner() + 2); // error[E0061]: this function takes 0 arguments but 1 argument was supplied
    dbg!(v.inner());
}
```

So... Compiler couldn't distinguish between methods of separate traits *even though* their signature is completely different!

Okay, nice try, nice try... But <s>Polska</s> the idea is not yet lost!

This time I noticed that compiler complains only about `SetInner` and tried swapping impls:

```rust
pub trait GetInner <T> {
    fn inner(&mut self) -> &T;
}

pub trait SetInner <T> {
    fn inner(&mut self, inner: T);
}

pub struct Wrapper <T> (T);

/// Swappy swap
impl <T> SetInner <T> for Wrapper <T> {
    fn inner(&mut self, inner: T) {
        self.0 = inner
    }
}

/// Swappy swap
impl <T> GetInner <T> for Wrapper <T> {
    fn inner(&mut self) -> &T {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Wrapper(0);
    dbg!(v.inner()); // error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
    v.inner(4); // error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
    dbg!(v.inner()); // error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
    v.inner(v.inner() + 2); // error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope x 2
    dbg!(v.inner()); // error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
}
```

Weird, errors are completely different now. But this doesn't help me...

I ask for a bright guidance from above: is there any way to implement my wish into reality, or current Rust(even nightly) is not yet prepared for such an 'advanced technology'?

Comment: Instead of "overloading", have you considered using an optional argument / argument with a default value?  It doesn't hurt anything if the "setter" call also returns the current value, you end up with something along the lines of `int inner(optional<int> newValue = Missing) { if (newValue != Missing) internalStorage = *newValue; return internalStorage; }`, where I'm claiming that this C++/C#/Java one-liner serves as pseudocode for the purposes of Rust discussion.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer misses one sliiight thing - Rust does *not* have default function parameters, aside of that - makes sense :)

Comment: I guess the answer is yes, but just to be sure: do the functions need access to the struct's fields?

Comment: Um... No? If that function is not a method, of course. Or struct is a dataclass. Or some other reason. But where have you seen such a function?

Comment: @Doubtful I mean `inner()`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, imagine that I have dsome customizable type user can shape to fit his needs? E.g. window - you can change or get its title, can't you? Forgot to mention, `inner` itself is *not* a field user has access to, it's a getter that can have something more inside, so technically user does not have access to the data, only through getters/setters - in the best traditions of OOP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to overload a function with different numbers of arguments (using traits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236166/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-function-with-different-numbers-of-arguments-using)

Comment: @Herohtar The OP also mentions overloading via implementing `Fn*`, so I'm unsure this is a duplicate (but unsure it is not, either).

Comment: @Herohtar yeah, that works, but the problem is that you *cannot* reach a constant through a dot syntax(and all the other ways that are mentioned in the post you gave are kinda ugly, I'm doing this in the first place for convenience of user's usage).

Comment: @Herohtar and no, that does not answer my question because I am looking for a way to call such functions without having pain in the neck, like in the answers of that topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't. Don't implement overloading in Rust. Don't even try. This is not  a good Rust API design. Rust does not use overloading. Rust should not use overloading. Use traits.

---

Sure, but still, *can we*?

The trait approach does not work with *multiple* traits, but it will work with a *single generic* trait (though the call is... not convenient):

```rust
trait Overload<Args> {
    type Output;
    fn foo(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}

struct Data(i32);

impl Overload<()> for Data {
    type Output = i32;
    fn foo(&mut self, (): ()) -> i32 { self.0 }
}

impl Overload<(i32,)> for Data {
    type Output = ();
    fn foo(&mut self, (v,): (i32,)) { self.0 = v; }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Data(0);
    v.foo((123,));
    dbg!(v.foo(()));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0aa490ff9fb63b0e17434e8e71bc424c).

I haven't (yet?) found a way to make the `Fn*` approach works, sadly.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion on topic of good or bad API design, but let me explain my point. I just think that this:
```rust
println!("{}", wrapper.inner());
wrapper.inner(4);
```
is slightly less ugly than this:
```rust
println!("{}", wrapper.inner());
wrapper.set_inner(4);
```
But you have a point, I think that maybe I was wrong when I decided to do it, but still - question is not *shall we*, but *can we*

Comment: @Doubtful I'm not going to argue about opinions, but there seems to be a pretty strong agreement among the Rust community that you should not mock overloading at least currently (the debate is when considering adding it to the language, and it's always very loud). Anyway, that's why I also answered the "can we", but I think every SO visitor should know/remember the "don't overload".

Comment: But... why? Okay, okay, I know that Rust has traits, that's very powerful and cool and etc., but many other languages(such as the monster C++, or Java, or C#, or Python,  and so on) have overloading and that doesn't make any mess(of course, if it's used properly and if the language is not C++). I mean, that's great that Rust has 'new' technology, but that doesn't mean that we should deny another one, even if it is slightly worse.

Comment: @Doubtful Because most of the times the overloaded functions are not really the same and should have different names; because when they are not, most of the times it's just default values (and I do slightly support adding defaulted parameters to Rust, and not just I); because in many languages overloading was introduced because it was necessary (think constructors) and not because it was good; because the tiny amount of remaining cases do not justify adding such a big language feature; because overloading complicates reasoning about names, both for the programmer and for the compiler...

Comment: @Doubtful And I'm sure I forgot some things.

Comment: Hmm okay, makes sense. So, do you think that it would be better and more 'Rust-way' to use `inner` as getter and `set_inner` as a setter? However, what if I want to create a GLSL-like vec, that supports constructing vec from the very same method, will take multiple types of arguments, various number of arguments and would have default values? All for convenience of usage , so there is basically no way to implement such a thing without overlosding.

Comment: @Doubtful That's why I said "use traits". For example, without knowing much about the details, I would suggest creating a trait `IntoGlslVlue` and take `impl IntoGlslValue`.

Comment: Okay, but user still needs convenient API - how would you implement that: ```let v = vec2::new(2.0, 0.0); let k = vec3::new(v, 4.0)```?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman what's the logic behind the weird `(i32,)` syntax? it seems to work the same if you replace them with a normal `i32` type/value: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e24ff84da35241e38c8543a65841acb7)

Comment: @JeremyMeadows `(i32,)` is the one-element tuple containing `i32`; `i32` (or `(i32)`) is just `i32`. I used it for symmetry's sake, but using `i32` is fine.

Comment: @Doubtful I miss a lot of details to properly answer that. What is `vec2`? What is `vec3`? Are they homogeneous or heterogeneous? Maybe this is better suited for a new SO question.

Comment: Oh okay, vec2 and vec3 are aliases for a ```pub struct vec <T, const N: usize>```, that are, respectively, vec <f32, 2> and vec <f32, 3>. More precisely you can see it <a href="https://github.com/Roman-Tarasenko-27/rokoko">here(in the vec and vec/new modules)</a>.

Comment: @Doubtful I think the answer has made it clear that attempting to implement language features in a language that does not natively support it is dubious at best. Rust's designers have decided not to support function overloading. It makes type inference easier, encourages meaningful names, and reduces resolution logic. A Rust way of making `vec3::new(v, 4.0)` work would be *with a different function*, `Vec3::from_xy(v, 4.0)` for example. I understand you think its more readable with the same name, but different languages have different idioms.

Comment: Okay, got it. Maybe I should just use `set_inner` as a setter instead of trying to abuse the same name multiple times :) I guess I can close the topic now, can't I?

Answer (score 0):

mimicking the Tkinter ability in a *rustier* way:
*As mentioned by the OP – to allow the cascaded call of* `fn inner()` *the* `self` *parameter may not be mutual.*

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct SomeObject<T> {
    inner: RefCell<T>,
}

impl SomeObject<i32> {
    fn new() -> SomeObject<i32> {
        SomeObject { inner: RefCell::new(0), }
    }

    fn inner(&self, opt: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
        match opt {
            Some(n) => { *self.inner.borrow_mut() = n; n },
            None    => { *self.inner.borrow() },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let some_object = SomeObject::new();
    some_object.inner(Some(123));
    println!("{}", some_object.inner(Some(some_object.inner(None) + 2)));  // 125
}
```