# Functions that may or may not take an argument

Tags: rust

I'm designing an API and I currently wish to have a function that may or may not accept an argument with default behavior for empty arguments. Using enums works ok, but that requires the user to enter certain arguments which will add up quickly. My current implementation is this:

```
enum ArgType {
    Square,
    Circle,
    Triangle,
}

fn draw_image(arg: ArgType) {
    match arg {
        ArgType::Square => println!("Square!"),
        ArgType::Circle => println!("Circle!"),
        ArgType::Triangle => println!("Triangle!"),
        _ => println!("Empty argument, initiating default behavior!"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let circle = ArgType::Triangle;
    draw_image(Triangle);
    draw_image(); // Does not compile
}
```

Comment: I thought about using strings but that gets messy quickly. I'd also have to parse in "" to represent an empty argument-- followed by a bunch of if-statements which doesn't seem like a clean solution.

Comment: I had initially thought you were after the concert that c++ has called function overloading - but according to this answer here rust  doesn’t permit that. I think the answer under this is what sort of functionality you might be after. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236166/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-function-with-different-numbers-of-arguments-using

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `Option<T>`.

```rust
fn draw_image(arg: Option<ArgType>) {
    match arg.unwrap_or(ArgType::DefaultArgType) {
        ArgType::Square => println!("Square!"),
        ArgType::Circle => println!("Circle!"),
        ArgType::Triangle => println!("Triangle!"),
    }
}

//...

draw_image(Some(ArgType::Circle));
draw_image(None); // will use the default ArgType
```

If you don't want to use a default `ArgType`, but instead want a completely separate functionality, I'd just define another function that immediately invokes the default behaviour.

```rust
fn draw_image_default() {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a functionality called "[function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)".

Rust explicitely does not allow that. A longer discussion about the reasoning behind it can be found [here](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/justification-for-rust-not-supporting-function-overloading-directly/7012).

As a direct alternative, you can represent *optional* parameters via the [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) type. It can either be `Some(value)` or `None`.

With it, your code would look like this:

```
pub enum ArgType {
    Square,
    Circle,
    Triangle,
}

fn draw_image(arg: Option<ArgType>) {
    match arg {
        Some(ArgType::Square) => println!("Square!"),
        Some(ArgType::Circle) => println!("Circle!"),
        Some(ArgType::Triangle) => println!("Triangle!"),
        None => println!("Empty argument, initiating default behavior!"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let triangle = ArgType::Triangle;
    draw_image(Some(triangle));
    draw_image(None);
}
```

```
Triangle!
Empty argument, initiating default behavior!
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, function overloading is not possible in Rust and you can use `Option` to represent optional parameters. However this can be unwieldy if you have a lot of parameters and you expect that your users will only use a few at a time. In that case, typing all the `None` values for the other parameters can be quite tedious. In order to avoid that you can use the builder pattern, where you initialize a struct with the default values, then call methods to set the parameters you want and have an `execute` method to do the work:

```
#[derive (Debug)]
pub enum ArgType {
    Default,
    Square,
    Circle,
    Triangle,
}

#[derive (Debug)]
pub enum ArgColor {
    Default,
    White,
    Black,
}

pub struct ImageDraw {
    ty: ArgType,
    col: ArgColor,
    // ...
}

impl ImageDraw {
    fn default() -> Self {
        ImageDraw { ty: ArgType::Default, col: ArgColor::Default, /* ... */ }
    }

    fn with_type (self, ty: ArgType) -> Self {
        ImageDraw { ty, ..self }
    }

    fn with_color (self, col: ArgColor) -> Self {
        ImageDraw { col, ..self }
    }

    fn draw (self) {
        println!("Drawing {:?} in {:?}", self.ty, self.col);
    }
}

fn main() {
    ImageDraw::default()
        .with_type (ArgType::Triangle)
        .with_color (ArgColor::White)
        .draw();
    ImageDraw::default()
        .with_type (ArgType::Circle)
        .draw();
    ImageDraw::default()
        .with_color (ArgColor::Black)
        .draw();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2e9b6ba6604d22a4b8fde0f922f5932)